# Wrapper to show contacts in Database also

Tags: visualforce

Requirement
On Page

1. A pageblock table :- To show all contacts
2. A pageblock section :- to add contact and show it in pageblocktable

Visualforce page code:-

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtTestContact" value="{!lstTestContactWrapper}"
                                    var="testconwrapper">
                                    <apex:facet name="caption">Test Contacts<br />
                                        <br />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.title}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.fName}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.lName}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.ident}" rendered="false"/>             
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:outputPanel>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsTestContact" title="Test Person">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Title__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Surname__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.First_Name__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Position__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Details" Action="{!saveTestContact}" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex Class Code

```
public with sharing class Test 
{
    public string TestContact1Id {get;set;}
    public string TestContactId {get;set;}
    public Test_Contact__c Test1{get;set;}

    public Test(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
    {
        Test1 = new Test_Contact__c();
        this.application=(Application__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

        lstTestContactWrapper=new List<TestContactWrapper>();
    }
    public class TestContactWrapper
      {
        public Integer ident {get; private set;}
        public String fName {get; set;}       
        public String lName {get; set;}
        public String title {get; set;}

        public Test_Contact__c ap {get; set;}

        public TestContactWrapper(Integer inIdent,Test_Contact__c TestContact) 
        {         
            ap=TestContact;  
            ident=inIdent;   
            this.fName = TestContact.First_Name__c;
            this.lName = TestContact.Surname__c;
            this.title = TestContact.Title__c;
        }
      }
}



    public PageReference saveTestContact()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = null;


        TestContact1.Application__c = this.application.Id;
        insert TestContact1;

        lstTestContactWrapper.add(new TestContactWrapper(nextIdent++,TestContact1));

        // Refresh object bound to the page
        TestContact1 = new Test_Contact__c();

        return pageRef;
    }

}
```

Issue:- The List of wrapper shows only the contacts added through UI. 
It should also show the contacts in database.

Now:- It is just showing the contacts that are added when save button is clicked.

Comment: In your constructor you define an empty list: lstTestContactWrapper. You have to fill it yourself using SOQL and lstContactWrapper.add(....). When you click save, you actually add it to that list.

Comment: If you want to show contacts other then those added in this page then you need to query for them and add them as wrappers to the list of contact wrappers

Comment: When i tried to SOQL directly to list.. its giving illegal assignemnt

Comment: You'll probably need to poll periodically for new Contacts, otherwise your page won't know that they're added.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually query for the contacts in the DB that you want to show on the page and then add them to your list of wrappers.

**In your constructor**

```
public Test(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) {
    Test1 = new Test_Contact__c();
    this.application=(Application__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

    list<Contact> myContacts = [Select Id, Name, From Contact];  //You should add logic to get only those contacts you want

    List<TestContactWrapper> lstTestContactWrapper=new List<TestContactWrapper>();
    for(Contact c : myContacts){
        lstTestContactWrapper.add(new TestContactWrapper(yourIndentValue, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll work when the page is initially loaded, but won't refresh the page. For a dynamic page polling will be required.

Comment: correct.  You could add a getter for the lost of wrappers that will be reinitialized after the DMl so it would work following a rerender

Answer (score 1):

You should create a list in by querying data and then `rerender` the Pageblock Table or query data in `saveTestContact` method to get current data with all contacts.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtTestContact" value="{!lstTestContactWrapper}"
                                    var="testconwrapper">
                                    <apex:facet name="caption">Test Contacts<br />
                                        <br />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.title}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.fName}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.lName}" />
                                    <apex:column value="{!testconwrapper.ident}" rendered="false"/>             
</apex:pageBlockTable>

<apex:commandButton value="Save Details" Action="{!saveTestContact}" rerender="pbtTestContact" />
```

Initialize variables in constructor as:

```
public Test(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
    {
        Test1 = new Test_Contact__c();
        this.application=(Application__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

        lstTestContactWrapper = new List<TestContactWrapper>();     

        for(Contact con : [Select Id, Name From Contact LIMIT 1000] )
        {
           lstTestContactWrapper.add(new TestContactWrapper(con.name, con.firstname, otherParams));
        }

    }
```